# Javascript and PHP ajax call with multiple return values returns undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have the following code with which I'm trying to do an `AJAX` call that can return multiple values

```
    // Make an ajax call to insert a new row.
    // Newer jquery uses done and fail instead of success and error.
    $.post("add_row_item.php", {
      work_order_id: 1
    }).done(function(data) {
      // Ajax request was successful.
      console.log(data);
      // Check if database query produced errors.
      if(data.error != "") {
        alert('Error trying to add a row - ' + data.error);
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
      // Ajax request failed.
      var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
      alert('Error trying to add a row - ' + errorMessage);
    });
```

The `PHP` code encodes the return message as follows:

```
echo json_encode(array("error" => "Error: " . mysqli_error($con)));
```

I get the following on the browser console:

```
{"error":"Error: Table 'db.tutorials' doesn't exist"}
```

But the alert gives me an `undefined` in the message:

```
Error trying to add a row - undefined
```

Anybody know where I'm going wrong with the alert part?

Comment: Have you looked in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, that's where I got the `{"error":"Error: Table 'db.tutorials' doesn't exist"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is actually a string, `'{"error":"Error: Table 'db.tutorials' doesn't exist"}'`. You can convert it to an object using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

or alternatively, specify

```
dataType : "json"
```

to your ajax call and it will be automatically converted on receipt (see the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)).